# random.sample() returning the same random sequence every time?

Tags: python, random

I'm using python's random.sample(population, k) function to generate a set of random values from a list to create new permutations of that list.  The issue is that each time it runs through a loop, it's generating the *exact same* random sequence.  Why is this?  I even used random.seed(i) so that the i variable (changing each time through the loop) would seed it a different value each time.  Still the same sequence.  What gives!@

Here is how I'm using it:

```
def initialBuild(self):
    alphabet = self.alphabet
    for i in range (self.length):
        value = random.sample(alphabet, 1)
        alphabet.remove(value[0])
        self.finalWord.append(value[0])
    print "Final word = ", self.finalWord
```

which is just being called from the init method of an Individual class.  The init method is being called like so...

```
def buildPopulation(self, alphabet):
    #Initialize empty individuals
    for i in range(POPULATION_SIZE):
        self.population.append(Individual(alphabet))
```

and the init method looks like this...

```
def __init__(self, alphabet = []):
    self.length = len(alphabet)
    self.alphabet = alphabet
    self.initialBuild()
```

At the end, I'm printing a final word.  Here is the output of running this method twice:

> Final Word =  [[1150, 1160], [720,
> 635], [95, 260], [595, 360], [770,
> 610], [830, 610], [25, 185], [520,
> 585], [605, 625], [410, 250], [555,
> 815], [880, 660], [300, 465], [1220,
> 580], [1215, 245], [1250, 400], [565,
> 575], [1605, 620], [845, 680], [1170,
> 65], [795, 645], [525, 1000], [760,
> 650], [580, 1175], [420, 555], [25,
> 230], [345, 750], [700, 500], [725,
> 370], [1530, 5], [1740, 245], [875,
> 920], [415, 635], [1340, 725], [975,
> 580], [575, 665], [1465, 200], [830,
> 485], [660, 180], [475, 960], [685,
> 595], [145, 665], [510, 875], [845,
> 655], [650, 1130], [945, 685], [480,
> 415], [700, 580], [560, 365], [685,
> 610], [835, 625], [1320, 315]]
>
> Final Word =  [[1150, 1160], [720,
> 635], [95, 260], [595, 360], [770,
> 610], [830, 610], [25, 185], [520,
> 585], [605, 625], [410, 250], [555,
> 815], [880, 660], [300, 465], [1220,
> 580], [1215, 245], [1250, 400], [565,
> 575], [1605, 620], [845, 680], [1170,
> 65], [795, 645], [525, 1000], [760,
> 650], [580, 1175], [420, 555], [25,
> 230], [345, 750], [700, 500], [725,
> 370], [1530, 5], [1740, 245], [875,
> 920], [415, 635], [1340, 725], [975,
> 580], [575, 665], [1465, 200], [830,
> 485], [660, 180], [475, 960], [685,
> 595], [145, 665], [510, 875], [845,
> 655], [650, 1130], [945, 685], [480,
> 415], [700, 580], [560, 365], [685,
> 610], [835, 625], [1320, 315]]

Notice that these two are absolutely identical..

**Edit:** Since I'm having a hard time picking out code that I think will be useful, yet short enough to go into this post, I've posted a bunch of it on pastebin.  http://pastebin.com/f5f068391  This is hopefully a better alternative..  Thanks again

Comment: The "loop around" part of this is perfectly unclear.  I can't reproduce this behavior based on the code you've shared.

Comment: @S.Lott, the pastebin entry does make things reproducible (can't run because it's missing a data file, but that's easy to simulate); see the latest edit in my A for the several interacting bugs I've diagnosed so far in that code (none related to `random`, really) and my suggested fixes (and a suggested reorg, to use random.shuffle instead of the loop of random.sample-then-remove, which _is_ a little bit related to the functionality offered by `random`;-).

Comment: "I'm having a hard time picking out code that I think will be useful"  There's a trick to that.  Find the smallest piece of code that actually produces the problem.  It's sometimes hard to do this if you're blaming the wrong thing for your problem.  But paring the problem down to the smallest piece of code that shows the problem is a great debugging skill.

Comment: `random.sample(..., 1)[0]` is equivalent to `random.choice(...)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "generating the *exact same* random sequence".  Since you only give us a snippet that can't be run on its own, it's quite possible that there are bugs in other parts of your code that you choose not to show us -- I've tried adding the absolutely minimal amount of code needed to make your snippet run, i.e.:

```
import random

import string
def self(): pass
self.alphabet = list(string.lowercase)
self.finalWord = []
self.length = 4

for x in range(5):
  alphabet = self.alphabet
  for i in range (self.length):
      value = random.sample(alphabet, 1)
      alphabet.remove(value[0])
      self.finalWord.append(value[0])
  print "Final word = ", self.finalWord
```

and here's what I see when I run this self-sufficient script a few times:

```
$ python sa.py 
Final word =  ['y', 'm', 'u', 'z']
Final word =  ['y', 'm', 'u', 'z', 'h', 'b', 'c', 's']
Final word =  ['y', 'm', 'u', 'z', 'h', 'b', 'c', 's', 'x', 'l', 'r', 'n']
Final word =  ['y', 'm', 'u', 'z', 'h', 'b', 'c', 's', 'x', 'l', 'r', 'n', 'q', 'a', 'k', 'e']
Final word =  ['y', 'm', 'u', 'z', 'h', 'b', 'c', 's', 'x', 'l', 'r', 'n', 'q', 'a', 'k', 'e', 'p', 'd', 'j', 'w']
$ python sa.py 
Final word =  ['k', 'v', 'o', 'd']
Final word =  ['k', 'v', 'o', 'd', 'q', 'p', 'w', 'l']
Final word =  ['k', 'v', 'o', 'd', 'q', 'p', 'w', 'l', 'n', 'u', 'g', 't']
Final word =  ['k', 'v', 'o', 'd', 'q', 'p', 'w', 'l', 'n', 'u', 'g', 't', 'i', 'r', 'e', 'f']
Final word =  ['k', 'v', 'o', 'd', 'q', 'p', 'w', 'l', 'n', 'u', 'g', 't', 'i', 'r', 'e', 'f', 's', 'c', 'j', 'z']
$ python sa.py 
Final word =  ['o', 'a', 'g', 't']
Final word =  ['o', 'a', 'g', 't', 'k', 'j', 'y', 'w']
Final word =  ['o', 'a', 'g', 't', 'k', 'j', 'y', 'w', 'z', 'l', 'i', 's']
Final word =  ['o', 'a', 'g', 't', 'k', 'j', 'y', 'w', 'z', 'l', 'i', 's', 'u', 'p', 'f', 'm']
Final word =  ['o', 'a', 'g', 't', 'k', 'j', 'y', 'w', 'z', 'l', 'i', 's', 'u', 'p', 'f', 'm', 'h', 'e', 'q', 'v']
```

As you see, that's anything **but** "the exact same random sequence" -- it's changing each and every run, just as expected.

I imagine I've read your mind incorrectly when trying to make your code executable, and that you mean it to be used very differently than my tiny script uses it -- but then mind-reading is an unreliable art (which is why it would be so much better if you posted a self-contained, **runnable** example, made as tiny as it can be while still reproducing your problem, rather than forcing us to try and read your mind!-).

Why don't you tweak the stand-alone script I've just posted by the minimal needed amount to make it closer to your intended use, and to reproduce the problem you observe?  **Then** it will be so much easier and more productive for us to spot any issue your code may have and suggest the best way to fix it!

**Edit**: the OP's code as pasted in pastebin has two bugs that have absolutely nothing to do with `random` and combine to produce the OP's observed behavior.  Here's the relevant part of the code, redacted:

```
class Phenotype:
   ...
   chromosome = []

   def __init__(self, alleles = []):
    self.length = len(alleles)
    self.alleles = alleles
    self.initialBuild()

   def initialBuild(self):
    alleleSet = self.alleles
    for i in range (self.length):
        value = random.sample(alleleSet, 1)
        alleleSet.remove(value[0])
        self.chromosome.append(value[0])
```

OK, there's another bug here (using old, legacy classes in new code, instead of shiny new style classes which should always be used), but that's not what's biting the OP (yet), so we'll just mention it in passing;-).

Bug 1: since neither `__init__` nor any other method ever do an assignment `self.chromosome = ...`, all the mentions of `self.chromosome` in the code actually refer to the one and only list `Phenotype.chromosome` which all instances of the `Phenotype` class share.  So inevitably **all** such instances will **always** have exactly the same, identical `chromosome`, no matter what.  Fix: add `self.chromosome = []` in `__init__` (better also to remove the class-level variables because they do no good whatsoever and only confuse the issue).

Bug 2: look at the following lines of code again to spot it:

```
    self.alleles = alleles
       ...
    alleleSet = self.alleles
       ...
        alleleSet.remove(value[0])
```

Got it?  `self.alleles` and the local name `alleleSet` are all references to **exactly** the one and the same `alleles` set (or list, actually) that's passed in -- so the `remove` call i **altering** the collection that's passed in.  So that collection's left empty after the very first Phenotype is instantiated (which is why despite Bug 1 the chromosome doesn't keep growing: because the alleles collection is left empty forevermore).

Fix: make a copy, e.g. `alleleSet = list(self.alleles)`, to avoid damaging the original collection.

Better fix: what you're doing is an **extremely** convoluted way to spell much simpler code such as:

```
self.chromosome = list(self.alleles)
random.shuffle(self.chromosome)
```

i.e., just get a random permutation.  Building a random permutation by doing N separate samples and removing each sample from the collection as it's generated is a really round-about, slow and complicated way to attack an extremely simple problem!-)

Comment: I shall also add more code :)  I've added the output of running this method twice, but hold on and I'll edit more, thanks!

Comment: Yep, your problems are completely different, let me edit the answer to explain.

Comment: Wow, unreal.  Thanks for the detail.  Using classes in python for the first time and it has me a little tied up.  Thanks for the effort, and for telling me about random.shuffle!

Comment: @AlexMartelli, you top my list of famous quotes with *mind-reading is an unreliable art* !

Answer (score 6):

Do not change the seed for every sample.  That breaks the random number generator and absolutely assures that it's not random.

Set the seed exactly once.  And never change that value again while your application is running.

The Random Number generator starts with a known, constant seed.  Each time you run, you should get the same sequence.  Setting no seed gives a predictable sequence.  Setting any constant seed (like `i` in the example) gives a predictable sequence.

If you want an unpredictable sequence, you need an unpredictable seed.  Use the time-of-day, or some bytes read from /dev/random as seed values.  Once.

Consider this as a simplification.

```
word = random.sample( alphabet, length )
```

It seems to produce different sequences for me.

```
>>> import string, random
>>> alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
>>> random.sample( alphabet, 5 )
['x', 'p', 's', 'k', 'h']
>>> random.sample( alphabet, 5 )
['y', 'h', 'u', 'n', 'd']
```

Comment: The seed was added after the random sampling wasn't changing.  This doesn't really solve anything.  The issue isn't that it's identical each time the program runs.  It's identical each time the *loop* runs.  It gives me the exact same output a thousand times in one run of the application.

Comment: It's producing different sequences for me, but when I loop around and recreate a list I get the identical one.  Hold on, I will edit with my output.

Answer (score 1):

```
value = random.sample(alphabet, 1)
```

From what I've gathered by trial and error, this iterates a random val from your population, and assigns it to "value". After that, "value" will always be that first random val. It doesn't iterate randomly again, it just sticks with the val that was assigned to value.

Instead of:

```
self.finalWord.append(value[0])
```

Try this:

```
self.finalWord.append(random.sample(alphabet, 1)[0])
```

I haven't tested this, so I'm not 100% sure it will work. But regardless, if I'm not mistaken, it should elucidate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering the same thing, then I realized it's because Python locks the random value until you run the random number code again. In other words, the random number function needs to be IN the while-loop, and not above it. Doing the latter causes the same established random number to repeat again and again once the loop starts.

Here's a simple example that runs 20 Trials of a Random Integer between 1 and 10:

```
#CORRECT version:
x = 1
y = 1
while x<=20:
    number = random.randint(1,10)
    print("Trial", y, "is", number)
    x = x + 1
    y = y + 1

#INCORRECT version:

number = random.randint(1,10)
x = 1
y = 1
while x<=20:
    print("Trial", y, "is", number)
    x = x + 1
    y = y + 1
```