# Random selection of sample resulting in same sample selection each each time

Tags: python, random

`random.sample()` produces the same result each time it is run with or without any seed.
The code is

```
import copy
import sys
import random
import numpy as np
for _ in range(5):

# seedValue = random.randrange(sys.maxsize)
# random.seed(seedValue)
aa = {(10, 11): 1, (10, 12): 1, (11, 10): 2, (11, 12): 2, (12, 10): 2, (12, 11): 2}
aa = {10: 1, 11: 1, 12: 2, 13: 2, 14: 2, 15: 2}

sampleDict_copy = copy.deepcopy(aa)
updated_users = []

while len(updated_users) < 6:

    itemMaxValue = max(sampleDict_copy.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
    listOfKeys = list() 
    # Iterate over all the items in dictionary to find keys with max value
    for key, value in sampleDict_copy.items():
        if value == itemMaxValue[1]:
            listOfKeys.append(key)


    listOfKeys = np.asarray(listOfKeys)
    remaining_capacity = 6 - len(updated_users)
    if remaining_capacity > 0:
        print(f"remaining_capacity = {remaining_capacity}, listOfKeys = {listOfKeys}")
        if len(listOfKeys) > remaining_capacity: ## listOfKeys can be filled with some combination
            updated_users.extend(random.sample(listOfKeys, remaining_capacity)) ## problem occurring here
        else: ## entire listOfKeys can be entered
            updated_users.extend(listOfKeys)
    
    
    for items in listOfKeys:
        del sampleDict_copy[items] 
print(f"updated_users = {updated_users}")
```

But I tried with a string as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168648/random-sample-returning-the-same-random-sequence-every-time) answer and here I get different results

```
import string, random
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
print(random.sample( alphabet, 5 ))
# result =  ['x', 'p', 's', 'k', 'h']
print(random.sample( alphabet, 5 ))
# result = ['y', 'h', 'u', 'n', 'd']
```

In general, where should the seed be provided? My objective is to get a different sample at each time the loop is run.

EDIT: Solution for anyone finding this question in the future

```
import copy
import sys
import random
import numpy as np
for _ in range(5):

    # seedValue = random.randrange(sys.maxsize)
    # random.seed(seedValue)
    aa = {(10, 11): 1, (10, 12): 1, (11, 10): 2, (11, 12): 2, (12, 10): 2, (12, 11): 2}
    aa = {10: 1, 11: 1, 12: 2, 13: 2, 14: 2, 15: 2}

    sampleDict_copy = copy.deepcopy(aa)
    updated_users = []

    while len(updated_users) < 6:

        itemMaxValue = max(sampleDict_copy.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
        listOfKeys = list() ## covered UAVs that will be removed once added to the selected_UAVs
        # Iterate over all the items in dictionary to find keys with max value
        for key, value in sampleDict_copy.items():
            if value == itemMaxValue[1]:
                listOfKeys.append(key)

        remaining_capacity = 6 - len(updated_users)
        if remaining_capacity > 0:
            print(f"remaining_capacity = {remaining_capacity}, listOfKeys = {listOfKeys}")
            updated_users.extend(random.sample(listOfKeys, len(listOfKeys)))
        for items in listOfKeys:
            del sampleDict_copy[items] 
    print(f"updated_users = {updated_users}")
```

Comment: `random.sample` appears not to be called at all in your first code block.  Also check that code's indentation.

Comment: You are using `random.seed()` incorrectly. ***Don't*** pass it the same value every time. When you do pass it the same value each time, it will generate the same "random" sequence each time. When you don't pass it anything, it will seed itself with the current system time and produce different sequences of number.

Comment: @martineau won't `seedValue = random.randrange(sys.maxsize)`  this generate a different value each time?

Comment: No, because `sys.maxsize` is a constant so you would be passing it the same value every time it was run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is completely deterministic.

The only non-deterministic thing in your while loop is

```
if len(listOfKeys) > remaining_capacity:
    updated_users.extend(random.sample(listOfKeys, remaining_capacity))
```

But this is never reached because the condition is false.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [`np.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) method from `numpy` library which has built-in random seed, works with any list. Should work fine in your case.

Comment: I tried it too, get the same result as this.